# Firefox window became grayscale

Tags: 18.04, firefox

After start of Firefox it's ok, colorful, but after any modal window (save or open file for example) Firefox became grayscale, till reboot. All other window/programs or new firefox windows (private or regular) is OK.

[image: Screenshot of grayscale window and normal]

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version and desktop environment?

Comment: https://termbin.com/oyq5

Comment: That's happened not only with Fitefox, but with any program after modal window (for example Libre Write after Print dialog window), also dialog window is hidden and you can see it only after minimize and maximize main window.

Answer (score 0):

After set to default in gnome-tweak-tool and disable of attach dialog window to parent window in "Window settings" I fixed it....